# OnComponentOrder flow and tMap connections in Talend

Tags: talend

I have the following flow:

- 1 Component that needs to be executed to extract from MYSQL a certain
  timestamp
- 3 MYSQL inputs that needs to use that timestamp
- 1 tMap which needs to get the 3 mysql input

However, I am not allowed to connect the 3 mysql into the single tMap because they are depending on the first component (through OnComponentOk) but with different order. How do I orchestrate this sort of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute a query and set a global variable using the tSetGlobalVar component (referencing row1.mydate, for example), then in each of your queries going into tMap, reference the global variable like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE mydate >= '" + (String) globalMap.get("myDate") + "';"
```

Two subjobs, one for getting the variable and storing it, and another for doing your three queries into tMap, etc.

[image: example job]

Comment: Are the tMysqlInput_3 and tMySqlInput_4 executed as well after tMySqlInput_1, and if yes, why?

Comment: They are in different subjobs. The first blue box you see is the first subjob, it will execute, then if it executed Ok, then the second subjob will execute (the second blue box). OnSubjobOk is a little misleading with it's arrow "starting" on the first component. It's really subjob to subjob.

Comment: why is the onSubJubOk attached to the tMySqlInput1 and what happens if the tSetGlobalVar throw an exception?

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain. I'll try a different way, sorry. The trigger attaches to the first component of the subjob. It does not mean that the first component itself is solely responsible for the triggering. It's actually the entire blue box that triggers OnSubJobOk once everything is completed successfully.  If the second component fails, the subjob fails and the next is not executed.