# Talend equivalent of Datastage "Dataset" or store intermediate result in talend

Tags: dataset, etl, talend, datastage

I'm trying to find the Talend equivalent of IBM Infosphere Datastage "Dataset" component or in other words What is the best way to store intermediate results in talend? the purpose of storing the result is to use it in some other job as a source.

Thanks
MJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do...

First, there is `tHashOutput` and `tHashInput`.  You can use this to store rows for later use.   It's pretty straight-forward.  You send a data flow to `tHashOutput`, and pull that same data from `tHashInput`. There are some options that you'll want to look at on these components.

Second... if you just need some temporary variables... `tSetGlobalVar`. Basically you can set a variable with that component, then reference it with something like `(String) globalMap.get("myVar")` (assuming it is a String format... change as necessary).

I answered a previous question using it, so you can see a more detailed example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705368/3148478